# Ошибка не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок gnome-screenshot

Tags: linux, debian

При нажатии на кнопку "PrintScreen", OpenBox выдает мне ошибку:

> Не удалось выполнить процесс-потомок "gnome-screenshot"

Порывшись в гугле, я нашел несколько статьей, где написали переназначить клавишу "PrintScreen" с команды "gnome-screenshot" на что-то свое.

В файлах `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml`, `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` и `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml.save` я переназначил клавиши на выполнение команды "xfce4-screenshooter", однако ошибка все равно осталась!

Как исправить ее?

---

У меня Debian 8 Jessit + LXDE

Comment: `which xfce4-screenshooter`, `which gnome-screenshot`? Если этих программ нет, то и не удивительно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установить нужный скриншотер? Вообще, для lxde родной скриншотер - scrot, и он прекрасно работает в опенбоксе. (Не забудь поставить его)